# Likes, Dislikes & Views using Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm working on a News Model where I want to perform the likes, dislikes & no of views functionality using the Django Rest Framework(ModelViewset). I have created a model for it

Models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    NEWS_TYPE = (('Images','Images'),('Multi-Images','Multi-Images'),('Image-Text','Image-Text'),
                 ('Audio-Video','Audio-Video'),('Audio-Video-Text','Audio-Video-Text'),('Audio','Audio'),
                 ('Audio-Text','Audio-Text'))
    POST_STATUS = (('Pending','Pending'),('Verified','Verified'),('Un-Verified','Un-Verified'),
              ('Published','Published'),('Mint','Mint'))
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Post Type', choices=NEWS_TYPE)
    title = models.TextField(verbose_name='News Title')
    content = models.TextField(verbose_name='News Content')
    hash_tags = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Hash Tags')
    source = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='News Source')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    views = models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='Views', blank=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='Likes', blank=True)
    dislikes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='Dislikes', blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='Status', choices=POST_STATUS)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.post_type)+ '-' +self.title
```

serializers.py

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
class PostAPI(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
```

I'm able to like, dislikes & view by multiple user. But at a same time same user is disliking the news how can I avoid these. Even how can I count the number of views, likes & dislikes. Is there anything that I have left out. Please help it would be a great support. Thanks alot.

Comment: When there is one-to-many relation you need to introduce a new table.

Comment: Can u please explain with the help of example.Plzz

Answer (score 0):

You will need another class something like below(I do not remember exact syntax so please adapt):

```
class Likes(models.Model):
    post_id <- make it a foreign key
    user_id <- this is the use performing likes or dislikes
    like <- Possible values are (-1, 0, 1)

   (post_id, user_id) is a unique constraint
```

Comment: I have changed the models by setting blank=True. So it worked. But how can I count the number of likes, dislikes & views?

Comment: You will use count function with filter on `post_id` and sum of like would be the total no. of likes or if you want to show likes and dislikes both then you count for `like=-1` and `like=1`

Comment: I have written a method for it in serializers. 
`def get_total_likes(self):
 return self.likes.users.count()`. Is this the correct way. Or else could you please explain with code.